# Unity3d, can't call Script from another script using GetComponent via string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to call a function from a gameobject script, from another gameobject script, but I need it to be using strings but when I try to do this

```
GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent("myscript").myfunction= false;
```

unity gives me the following error before I can run

```
Assets\GenericActor.cs(94,40): error CS1061: 'Component' does not contain a definition for 'myfunction' and no accessible extension method 'myfunction' accepting a first argument of type 'Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: You need to cast the result of `GetComponent` to the type of the script.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain in more detail?

Comment: `GetComponent` returns an object of type `GameObject`. `GameObject` does not have a method called `myfunction`. You need to cast the result of `GetComponent` to the type `myscript`.

Comment: If that is not clear, go look up typecasting.

Comment: Also, are you really trying to assign a value to a function? That makes zero sense.

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: Basically, something like: `((myscript)GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent("myscript")).myfunction = false;`

Comment: @3Dave forgive me if I'm wrong, I'm a bit rusty, isn't there a generic form of GetComponent for this? Something like .GetComponent<MyType>("my script")?

Comment: @Mort432 almost ... it would rather simply be `GetComponent<myscript>()` without additional parameter ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
MyScript playerScript = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<MyScript>().myfunction = false;
```

It could also be done with a tag:

```
MyScript playerScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<MyScript>().myfunction = false;
```

also,
if you're calling a function like void MyFunction(bool myBool) you'd use

```
MyScript playerScript = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<MyScript>().MyFunction(false);
```